# How can I get my dog to obey and do his business in the garden instead of inside the house?

Tags: dogs, training, toilet-training

N.B.: I'm not living at the same location as my fiancée right now, so I can't take action directly.

---

My fiancée has a Shih Tzu who'll soon be 5 years old. He had a habit of refusing do his business outside (when it's cold, raining, etc.), and did it inside the house instead.

But lately, he doesn't want to get outside at all, and is doing his business in spots where he usually doesn't do it (below a table for example). Sometimes, he does it barely 2 minutes after refusing to go outside, despite the weather being warm and it's not raining.

Today, he even did his business in front of my fiancée, despite yelling at him. He stopped only when he was done. We initially thought it was linked to the death of a recent family member, but he started acting like this months before.

My fiancée considered using a repellant, but she changed her mind when she realised the product was a health hazard for pets.

Although they (my fiancée and her mother) are yelling on him (the dog), clapping their hands or hitting the ground, he still refuses to do his business outside. For a while now, he's being stubborn and refuses to obey (for example, when he's jumping around or chew softly and we tell him to stop, he's not listening either).

He's been to the veterinarian 3 months ago, and they didn't find anything weird about the dog (his health is good, and his behaviour wasn't out of the ordinary). He usually is an excited dog, but he's not a bad one.

How can she get the dog to start obeying again, and do his business outside in the garden?

Comment: Did anything change in the life of the dog recently, just before the new behavior occurred? It might be a sign of stress or of revolt.

Comment: @virolino From what I've been told, nothing much. Everything has been going the same way, beside the family member being gone (though it happened much later, after his behaviour changed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My son and his wife asked me to babysit their two Shih Tzu dogs for one month.  The dogs were over 3 years old and were not house trained.  I accepted the babysitting dog and told the "parents" that their dogs would never mess in my house.

So, the first day they came, I walked them 4-6 times.  They were spoiled and acted like they wouldn't leave the house.  I simply put on their leashes and walked out the door as if in a hurry.  Each time, they peed, I praised them.  From that point on, they never had an accident again.  Once they went home, the "parents" were astounded when the dogs refused to go inside the house and cried at the door.  Those lovely little dogs had not learned to enjoy outside walks and the concept of peeing, pooping and vomiting away from where they ate.

It was an easy success as they were happily introduced to a new routine with no arguing or excuses.

I hope this helps you.